How to translate formally this sentence with 'and, not, or'?
Let p, q, and r be the propositions “The package was delivered on time,” “The package was damaged during transit,” and “The customer received the correct item,” respectively. How will the sentence “The package was delivered on time and the package was not damaged during transit or the customer received the correct item” be translated into logical form?
(p ^ ¬q) v r
p ^ (¬q v r)
Is it 1 or 2?

Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. This will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

You have to parse it... Maybe:as "(The package was delivered on time and the package was not damaged during transit) or the customer received the correct item”"

Honestly, I think natural language is confusing here. It could be either one.

Same as Matti (the parenthesis in Mauro's comment could be put the other way: The package was delivered on time and (the package was not damaged during transit or the customer received the correct item)). Btw, please  format your formulas.
